# Reorientation of Accelerometer axes to car's axes

Tags: android, orientation, accelerometer

I am working on an application where I need to reorient accelerometer axes according to car's axes. Could anyone help me out how I can achieve this ?

What I mean by this is : If I keep my phone in any direction in the car, it should align with car's axes. This is a part of my android application. Plz help me.

Thanks.